# Should I declare UserDefaults as a variable or not?

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I'm worried about whether I should declare UserDefaults as a variable or not like the following code:

**Pattern A**

```
let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard

if let userDefaults.object(forKey: "isFirstLaunch") {

}
```

**Pattern B**

```
if let UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isHardModeEnabled") as Bool {

}
```

Which is the best way and is there any difference between the two ways?

Comment: Nothing is different there. If you are going to use multiple places in class means go for **Pattern A** otherwise use **Pattern B**

Comment: UserDefault's `UserDefaults.standard` it's self singletone class so it doesn't matter what way you are using

Comment: In pattern a, you are introducing an extra variable, it is good if you are accessing the user defaults many times from the same class/function. Also in pattern A you are missing `as Bool` type casting, it can result in unwanted behavior (like you stored string instead of bool and your program expecting a bool. But the above if let check will be true even if there is a string instead of bool)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are the correct ways to use `UserDefaults` and it depends on your requirement like where you can use `Pattern A` and `Pattern B` like if you want to use `UserDefaults.standard` many places in your `ViewController` then you can declare

```
let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
```

outside your methods and access it anywhere in your `UIViewController` class or you can declare it as a global and you can use it any where into your project.

But if you don't have much use of it then you can just use

```
if let UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isHardModeEnabled") as Bool {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both ways are correct and you can use it in anyway you want, except that there will be one extra variable defined in Pattern A.

> [SwiftyUserDefaults](https://github.com/radex/SwiftyUserDefaults) Modern Swift API for NSUserDefaults.

Answer (score 0):

Actually both are same.

`UserDefaults.standard` will return the singleton instance of UserDefaults.

You can choose any of method for your convenience.

If you need to use userDefaults frequently, you can shorten `UserDefaults.standard` into a variable.

```
let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard

if let defaults.object(forKey: "isFirstLaunch") {

}
```